# modification to "Spring Roo + GWT"'s default UI and interactivities

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

If someone have a different need for UI and interactivites than what is provided by 'gwt setup', what is the best way to accommodate it?

Suppose the requirement are things like these:
- introduce 'dual control' to all forms,
- use GXT instead of standard GWT widgets

Thinking the top off my head, options are these:
- hack the google plugin and accommodate the changes there,
- let roo generate the default UI, and make manual modification from there on.

Which one would you prefer?

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the second option, use Roo to generate your skeleton, use [Push-In refactor, lose Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html) and go from there manually.